# How to update last login time

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: List of Account]

**This is my Sql**

```
mysql_query('UPDATE `useraccounts` SET `LAST_LOGIN` = now() WHERE `ACCOUNT_PASSWORD` ');
```

**Problem is:**
Only the staff account is updating.

What should I do is there something wrong. I tried also `LIKE` but still Staff account updating Time.

I need to update Admin Account too.

Please help me

**Newbie programmer here sorry**

Comment: How are you actually comparing the user password against the database?  You didn't store your passwords as clear text, did you?

Comment: I use WHERE ACCOUNT_PASSWORD because it same value as ACCOUNT_NAME but it's not working

Comment: your where clause is incomplete. it should contain `where account_password='something?'`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `LAST_LOGIN` =/= `LastLogin`

Comment: Only Sql query i try in Localhost i use Xampp. Is it possible to fix using SQL QUERY only?

Comment: @DexterDave I think you didn't understand the kitten reference. In your code, you used `mysql_query`; which is currently not recommended for use. You should use `mysqli` (for mysql db only) or `PDO` functions for database operations using PHP. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for more info about `mysqli` and `PDO` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, shift your code to `mysqli`.

Here is query which will be helpful.

```
$query = "UPDATE `useraccounts` SET `LAST_LOGIN` = now() WHERE `ACCOUNT_id` = `LoggedInUser`");
```

Comment: What should i replace to LoggedInUser?

Comment: Normal way is when you verify password, get ID, and pass here ID of that record.